# Ошибка в Android Studio при обновление gradle

Tags: java, android, android-gradle

Ошибка:

```
Failed to resolve: 
in.championswimmer:SimpleFingerGestures_Android_Library:1.2
```

Пример реализации:
https://github.com/championswimmer/SimpleFingerGestures_Android_Library

API:
https://championswimmer.in/SimpleFingerGestures_Android_Library/documentation/reference/in/championswimmer/sfg/lib/package-summary.html

Вот что мне удалось найти:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26620064/4827341

build.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
if (enable_plugin_kotlin) {
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.crdev.launcher"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30

        flavorDimensions "versionCode"
        multiDexEnabled false

        buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_TEST_BUILD", "false"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_GPLAY_BUILD", "false"
        buildConfigField "String[]", "DETECTED_ANDROID_LOCALES", "${findUsedAndroidLocales()}"
        buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_DATE", "\"${getBuildDate()}\""
        buildConfigField "String", "GITHASH", "\"${getGitHash()}\""
        resValue "string", "manifest_package_id", "com.benny.openlauncher"

        resValue 'string', 'app_name', "iPhone Launcher"

        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0"

    }

    /*productFlavors {
        flavorDefault {
        }

        flavorGplay {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_GPLAY_BUILD", "true"
        }

        flavorGplayPreAlpha {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_GPLAY_BUILD", "true"
            buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_GPLAY_PREALPHA_BUILD", "true"
            resValue 'string', 'app_name', "OL PreAlpha"

            versionCode = Integer.parseInt(new Date().format('yyMMddhh'))
            versionName = "0.5.8-pre-alpha"
            applicationId "com.benny.openlauncherprealpha"
        }

        flavorTest {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_TEST_BUILD", "true"
            resValue 'string', 'app_name', "OL Nightly"

            versionCode = Integer.parseInt(new Date().format('yyMMdd'))
            versionName = new Date().format('yyMMdd')
            applicationId "io.github.openlauncherteam.openlauncher.test"
        }
    }
*/
    sourceSets {
        if (enable_plugin_kotlin) {
            main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            eachDependency { details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
                    if (details.requested.name != 'multidex' && details.requested.name != 'multidex-instrumentation') {
                        details.useVersion "${version_library_appcompat}"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-LGPL-2.1.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-LGPL-3.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-W3C-TEST'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.0'
}

dependencies {
    // Support libraries
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-preference-v14:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
//    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.0.0'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.6.0'
    implementation 'com.bartoszlipinski:viewpropertyobjectanimator:1.4.5'
    // UI Libs
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:fastadapter:3.2.3@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:fastadapter-commons:3.0.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:fastadapter-extensions:3.0.0@aar'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.7'
    implementation 'com.eightbitlab:blurview:1.3.3'
    implementation 'com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.4.3'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'
    implementation 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    implementation 'agency.tango.android:material-intro-screen:0.0.5'
    implementation 'cat.ereza:customactivityoncrash:2.2.0'
    implementation 'de.psdev.licensesdialog:licensesdialog:1.8.3'
    implementation 'com.jaredrummler:colorpicker:1.0.2'
    implementation group: 'net.qiujuer.genius', name: 'blur', version: '1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.romainpiel.shimmer:library:1.4.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.jaredrummler:colorpicker:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.chyrta:AndroidOnboarder:0.7'
    implementation 'in.championswimmer:SimpleFingerGestures_Android_Library:1.2.1'

    implementation('com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:2.0.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    implementation('com.github.turing-tech:MaterialScrollBar:12.4.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }

    // Tools
    implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:${version_library_butterknife}"
    if (enable_plugin_kotlin) {
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$version_plugin_kotlin"
    }

    // Processors
    def anpros = ["com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:${version_library_butterknife}"]
    for (anpro in anpros) {
        if (enable_plugin_kotlin) {
            kapt anpro
        } else {
            annotationProcessor anpro
        }
    }

}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: приложите пожалуйста код градл файла и ссылку на библиотеку, добавьте так же подробностей в вопрос

Comment: @Andrew Готово!

Comment: Почему у вас указана версия 'in.championswimmer:SimpleFingerGestures_Android_Library:1.2.1' когда согласно документации последняя версия 1.2?

Comment: @blind.falcon все равно не работает, это я просто проверял.

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста код build.gradle уровня всего приложения